# Allow embedding of gifly/gfycat

Tags: feature-request, chat

The only option to embed this kind of media is to link to the [bandwidth-hogging 256-color low-framerate gif version](http://zippy.gfycat.com/DefensivePastelCommongonolek.gif), which is a waste when [video tags are now things that have been existing for a while](https://gfycat.com/DefensivePastelCommongonolek).

Please bring audioless video playback to chat. Pretty please?

Comment: Why not just the WebM format, not limiting to a single host?

Comment: @random because arbitrary webm's also can have sound

Comment: Any update to this?